# Adding Multiple AD Users to Multiple Groups via CSV using PowerShell Columns are Group names not headers Users under group names

Tags: powershell, csv, multiple-columns

I need to move `ADUsers` to each `ADGroup` they are listed under each column, the columns are the group names themselves so `$_.groups` since there are no headers.

[image: Example CSV]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to loop through the column headers. You can obtain a list of these properties by using the **Get-Member** cmdlet.

```bsh
$usersToAdd = Import-CSV users.csv
$groups = ($usersToAdd | Get-Member | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" }).Name
```

From here you could loop through the groups querying the members that fall under each group in the original csv.

```bsh
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $users = $usersToAdd.$group
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

You may get some empty values if some columns have more users than others do, so perhaps you will want to check for that too.

```bsh
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $users = $usersToAdd.$group
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($user)) {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -Confirm:$false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response Ash! I will try this shortly to confirm. I found this script online that worked rather well Though I am still breaking this down to fully understand it. Thank you again for your help!!::

> ```
> > $rows = Import-Csv "C:\FILE.csv" 
> > $groups = @{} 
> > foreach ($header in $rows[0].PSObject.Properties.Name) { $groups[$header] = @() } 
> > foreach ($row in $rows) 
> > {
> >     [string[]]$keys = $groups.Keys
> >     foreach ($key in $keys)
> >     {
> >         if ($row.$key) { $groups[$key] += $row.$key }
> >     }
> > } 
> >foreach ($key in $groups.Keys) { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $key -Members $groups[$key] -Verbose }
> ```